# 403 Forbidden error when using mod_rewrite with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this .htaccess directives to prevent SQL injection attacks to my WordPress blog:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag\= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

My blog uses a JavaScript redirection to redirect the visitor from an opening page to the blog with the following query string parameters: `redir=1&ref=`

So the "ref" parameter is usually empty if the visitor comes from no referral set, for example he typed the title in the browser. In other cases the "ref" parameter has a value which shows for me where the visitor is coming from.

My problem is that at first visit I get a 403 error message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After removing the abovementioned directives from the .htaccess the problem also disappears. However I would like to use a modified version of these directives to prevent SQL injection attacks. What lines should I modify to prevent the attacks and get rid of the "403 forbidden" error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*).* [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Thx, the rules are still too restrictive, because if somebody clicks on a link in  a gmail email, gots a 403 error again. In this case the "ref" query string try to pass a value like this:
http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGiGAF2NA9-5MhMmwXDlT64bYKpNg

Comment: The problem is that you can delete them all. It is to you to choose those which are useful or not